# How do I simulate a slow internet connection (Edge/3g) on a mac. Is there a Firefox plugin?

Tags: iphone, firefox, plugins, connection

**Exact Duplicate**: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473465/firefox-plugin-to-simulate-slow-internet-connection

How do I simulate a slow internet connection (Edge/3g) on a Mac? Is there a Firefox plugin?

Comment: The accepted answer on the exact duplicate dos not work on OS X.

Comment: Link of the exact duplicate goes 404

Comment: As @tuxayo said, duplicate question link is broken.

Answer (score 19):

On a Mac or BSD, use:

```
sudo ipfw pipe 1 config bw 350kbit/s plr 0.05 delay 500ms
sudo ipfw add pipe 1 dst-port http
```

And to reset to your initial settings:

```
sudo ipfw flush
```

Comment: Note that ipfw isn't generally available on Linux.

Comment: os x > man ipfw > Note that use of this utility is DEPRECATED. Please use pfctl(8) instead.

Answer (score 17):

Apple now have an official developer tool called Network Link Conditioner which simulates different network conditions. It has some more powerful features that alternatives like SpeedLimit and Charlie — for example it can simulate packet loss and DNS delays as well as bandwidth and latency — and it is free.

Network Link Conditioner is provided with [Xcode](http://developer.apple.com/xcode/), with is a free download but is also a very large download!

[image: Apple Xcode Network Link Conditioner]

Ref: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24066/how-to-simulate-slow-internet-connections-on-the-mac

Comment: Note that in more recent versions of Xcode, the Network Link Conditioner has become a separate download which you install after Xcode. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11699805/where-is-network-link-conditioner-prefpane-in-osx-mountain-lion-and-xcode-4-4 for more details.

Answer (score 8):

[SpeedLimit](http://mschrag.github.com/) does the trick for me.

Comment: +1 for speedlimit which at least works, unlike Apple's Network Link Conditioner which crashes 100% of the time on my (and others') Mac

Comment: This worked for me once I turned it on and ran up/down speed tests. But then when I tested a flash uploader that I was wanting to limit the connection on it didn't work.

Answer (score 4):

[Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) and [Fiddler](http://www.fiddlertool.com/) are HTTP proxies that can throttle your speed, among other things. You can even tell your iPod or iPhone to use them, and capture all the traffic coming & going.

Comment: In Charles, I'm not sure if there is an option to have packet loss.

Answer (score 0):

When I was evaluating how a piece of software would work with a bad cell-card connection, I wrapped some tin foil around the antenna. It sounds dumb, but it worked really well; the signal dropped down to a single bar but was not gone completely.

I also tried putting the laptop in a microwave which ended up being not nearly as effective.

Answer (score -1):

Not that I know of. If you want to see how things look when they're loading you can use firebug and set breakpoints in the javascript, or breakpoints on your server. I always use this technique to see how things look when they're loading.

Another option is NetLimiter, I've heard it works but haven't tried it myself
http://www.netlimiter.com/