# Is there a way to limit processing power and network bandwidth for iPhone Simulator?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, limit, bandwidth

Is there a way to limit processing power and network bandwidth for iPhone Simulator?

This question is essentially a CPU and bandwidth limiting tool for specific program on Unix. Any recommendations...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As for network/bandwidth limitations, there's a really good tool called Network Link Conditioner included with XCode nowadays. Possible to use a number of presets as well as setting up your own configurations.

You can also check out:
[How do I simulate a slow internet connection (Edge/3g) on a mac. Is there a Firefox plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596780/how-do-i-simulate-a-slow-internet-connection-edge-3g-on-a-mac-is-there-a-fire/8060428#8060428)

**UPDATE:** Note that the Network Link Conditioner (as of iOS6) is available from the Settings > Developer menu on your iPhone (if it's marked as *Use for development*).

Comment: In Mavericks you have to do some extra stuff to get NLC open http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19100318/trouble-using-network-link-conditioner-on-os-x-mavericks

Answer (score 1):

To limit your bandwidth, you can try using http://mschrag.github.com/. It's a preference pane which helps you simulate several bandwidth configurations (Edge, 3G, etc).

Answer (score 0):

You could try using nice: http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?nice

At least that will help with the CPU problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [cpulimit](http://cpulimit.sourceforge.net/) to limit the CPU usage in term of percentage.

UPDATE: Read [this discussion](http://lists.netisland.net/archives/plug/plug-2004-09/msg00454.html) to know how to configure iptables to limit bandwidth per process.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the osx firewall to do this :

```
sudo ipfw add 1 pipe 1 ip from any to me src-port 80
sudo ipfw pipe 1 config bw 40KByte/s
```

Edit : it seems that the simulator use local ipv6 address, and ip6fw doesn't manage pipe and bandwidth limit. I've edited my code to be sure that localhost v4 (127.0.0.1) address is used.