# Trouble using Network Link Conditioner on OS X Mavericks

Tags: macos, networking, osx-mavericks

I'm trying to get Network Link Conditioner working on my machine that is running OS X Mavericks. I'm running Developer Preview 8 (the latest as of this writing). I downloaded the "Hardware IO Tools for Xcode 5 Developer Preview -  June 2013" to get the Network Link Conditioner pref pane. I have also tried the version of Network Link Conditioner from the previous Hardware IO Tools bundle which fails to open with a "Could not load Network Link Conditioner preference pane." error when trying to load it.

With the version for Xcode 5 I get one of two fail states.

First, when I open NLC and click the lock icon to "make changes" I see the administrator unlock window that says:

`com.apple.Network-Link-Conditioner.remoteservice.xcp wants to make changes. Type your password to allow this.`

When this shows up I am unable to enter my password. No keyboard characters are registered in the password field, or in any other application until I cancel the password prompt. I have no trouble with the equivalent dialog in any other preference panes.

Second, I am sort of able to get past the password issue by uninstalling the latest NLC pref pane, installing the previous version, uninstalling the previous version, and then re-installing the latest NLC preference pane. However, I note that the password dialog is different in this case.  I get the more generic:

`System Preferences wants to make changes. Type your password to allow this.`

In this second failed state, once I type in my password the NLC pref pane is fully accessible but has zero affect on my network link.

Has anyone been able to use the Network Link Conditioner successfully on OS X Mavericks?

**Update:**

The version of Hardware IO Tools released on October 22 and the final release of Mavericks appear to be working excellent.

Comment: Since Mavericks has not been released, you should (a) file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com/ and (b) ask at http://devforums.apple.com/ to see if anyone has found a workaround.

Comment: Best guess: NLC hasn't been updated for Mavericks. If you can, file a Radar.

Comment: Thanks. I've submitted a Bug Report to Apple for this.

Comment: I have the same issue but I'm not running Mavericks as yet - still on MountainLion. I have Xcode 5.0.2 and downloaded the latest Hardware IO Tools just now. When i try and install NLC it says "Could not load Network Link Conditioner preference pane."

Comment: I'm running xcode 5.1.1 with 10.9.4 and the jun '14 of h/w tool. It installs fine, but once i turn it on, it hangs. Anybody has this running on the latest builds?

Comment: Turns out you can only enable NLC with Administrator account. I filed a bug report.

Comment: this is still the case with macOS Sierra 10.12.3

Answer (score 28):

Try re-installing it. It fixed the issue for me, though I was having different error messages.

1. Open System Preferences, right-click (or control-click) on the Network Link Conditioner and click "Remove Network Link Conditioner" to remove it.
2. In Xcode got to the Xcode menu -> Open Developer Tool -> More Developer Tools...
3. In the browser window that opens, grab the most recent Hardware IO tools .dmg
4. Double click the "Network Link Conditioner.prefPane" on the disk image to install it.

Comment: My problem was that NLC had no effect for me. This solution only worked after removing the pref pane from trash as well. Thanks.

Comment: I had to: uninstall, restart, install latest, restart. That did the trick for me at least

Comment: it's a dmg download under Hardware IO Tools for Xcode at https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=for%20Xcode%20-

Comment: @WickyNilliams I confirm that !, none of the above worked but your tip worked perfectly
uninstall, restart, install, restart. only then it worked properly !

Comment: @MostafaTorbjørnBerg yeah I tried everything else too :) restarting every step of the way was the only thing that worked

Comment: @BenGoodwin Can't say I have any other suggestions other than making sure you download the *correct/latest* version of the tools from apple. I accidentally downloaded an older edition in the past. It installed without problem, would report it was working, but never did anything.

Comment: I confirm that only @WickyNilliams procedure in the exact order specified works. I tried to uninstall, install latest, restart but that didn't suffice.

Comment: This worked for me, but only because in the process of reinstalling, I ended up grabbing the "Hardware IO Tools for Xcode - October 2013" instead of "Hardware IO Tools for Xcode - Late July 2012". This is the equivalent of "unplug it, blow on the plug, and then plug it back in", but I can't complain, it works! +1 :D)

Comment: @WickyNilliams Thanks, this worked, you should post this as an alternate answer.

Comment: @aidaan + Kenny-Winker + pyeleven solved my problem! Thanks guys :)

Comment: For Xcode 8 it's called *Additional Tools for Xcode*

Comment: Mojave 10.14.3: install, reinstall, remove from trash, download ones more, and retry: **NLC does no effect**.

Answer (score 5):

How I got it solved was:

1. Uninstall "Network Link Conditioner", open System Preferences and press CTRL and click on the "Network Link Conditioner" icon. Select "Delete".
2. Restart Computer
3. Download "Hardware IO tools" dmg for your version on XCode, from [https://developer.apple.com/download/](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/) you have to be logged in for this.
4. Open it and Install "Network Link Conditioner"
5. Restart the computer one last time.

It should be working fine now!

Answer (score 4):

I was also having problems with Network Link Conditioner working after upgrading to Mavericks.  For me the problem was the default security settings after the upgrade that prevented software from running unless it came form the Mac App Store.

Updating this setting:

System Settings > Security & Privacy > General > Allow apps downloaded from: > Anywhere

and reinstalling the Network Link Conditioner pref pane fixed it for me. Without this setting you can install and enable it, but it has no effect and silently fails.

Answer (score 2):

On macOS Sierra v10.12.1 with Xcode 8.1, I tried a couple of the *Hardware IO Tools for Xcode* downloads. All of which resulted in a silent failure like @aidaan such that the Network Link Conditioner plain didn't do anything.

After finding this [discussion](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/66042), I uninstalled the previous *Hardware IO Tools for Xcode* components, and instead utilized the *Additional Tools for Xcode 8.1* downloaded from [the downloads page](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/), the Network Link Conditioner in the Hardware directory for that .dmg worked perfectly.

Comment: None of the suggestions above worked for me on Sierra w/ Xcode 8.1, this fixed it!

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful! It's no longer called *Hardware IO tools*